# dynamically detect if textbox value is change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to detect the change of a textbox even if that textbox value is not entered by user like the below scenario? I have some scenarios like when the page is loading for the first time the texbox get loaded with data.

```js
$("#txt1").change(function(){
  $("#txt2").val("1")
  //$("#txt2").change();
});

$('#txt2').on("change", function() {
  // some computation will happen here.
  alert("1");
});

$("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("#txt2").val("1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name='text1'>
<button id="btn1">
    Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value changed by **JavaScript** does not trigger any event so you just can't catch event in this case. 
You can implement a watcher to your input value using **interval**

```js
var oldValue = $("#txt2").val();
setInterval(function() {
    var currentValue = $("#txt2").val();
    if (currentValue !== oldValue) {
      $("#txt2").trigger("change");
      oldValue = currentValue;
    }
}, 100);

$("#txt1").change(function(){
  $("#txt2").val("1")
});

$('#txt2').on("change", function() {
  // some computation will happen here.
  alert("1");
});

$("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("#txt2").val("1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name='text1'>
<button id="btn1">
Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know that on textbox1 change event you are changing second textbox value, you need to trigger it manually

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#txt1").change(function () {

   $("#txt2").val("1")
   $("#txt2").trigger("change");

 });

 $("#txt2").change(function () {

    alert("1");

 });

})
```

Comment: If I do that, so it means all scenarios that is possible i need to put the code `$("#txt2").trigger('change');`

Comment: yes, you need to write it in all place where you want to trigger it.

Comment: is there any short way to do it?.

Comment: first try this solution and if it is worked then you can think for further operation. let me know what is your scenario ?